# Aligning an odd-width child within an even-width parent

Tags: html, css

In parent block with even block width value -
is it possible to position (or align) in the middle
this parent is a child with an odd width value?
For example, take a parent with a width of 10 pixels and a child with a width of 1 pixel.
Is it possible to position the child in the middle of such a parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, This can be done using translateX. The function takes float values.

```css
.parent{
width:10px;
height:10px;
background:black;
}
.child{
width:1px;
height:10px;
background:red;
transform:translateX(4.5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is decision is not help:
http://joxi.ru/gmv1nyvHeYQR5r
http://joxi.ru/VrwyX78con5RV2

Comment: The parent has a width of 100% which gives the output from 9.71667px to 9.73334px depending on the generated element.

Comment: Did you see the snippet I provided?
I think since in your code the width is not constant you can't use fixed values like 4.375px. It must be relative.

Comment: But eventually I have an absolute value in the browser - can't this property identify it?
if it couldn't do that at all then how did it align almost in the middle?
the element is still centered - just not very accurate.
this means that this property identifies the absolute size in the browser.

Comment: Try to include a snippet that represents your actual code. For a general question like what you asked first my code works.

Comment: it is not possible. real code is very complex.